# Confusion using shared preferences with multiple identical resources

Tags: android, mysql, xml, sharedpreferences

What I thought was going to be the easiest solution, is proving to be the most confusing.

I am creating an app that needs to reference information from multiple "accounts"... such as name, email address, acct number, password and a few other fields... approximately 15 items.    There can be as many as 15-20 of these accounts in this app depending on the user.   Each one will be manually added and the information filled in and stored.

I decided to use a Preference Fragment to make entering this information simpler because everyone is familiar with how Android Preference screens work and the information being entered is pretty straightforward.   Why create my own input screens when the built-in looks like it will work.

I asked on here opinions if I should store the data in the preference or an SQL database.     Basic consensus, depends on if I need to search or sort, might be easier in an SQL database.... otherwise, internally in preferences.

I created the code for the SQL database and then had some confusion on how to get the data in and out of the preference code.   I asked on here for some help in getting this to work.   Unfortunately, that sort of got lost and was again recommended that I store in pref instead.

So, I started looking into keeping it in pref files, again.

Because there are approximately 15 fields per account, and the possibility of 15 or more accounts, having a single preference XML file with 225+ entries (name1, name2, name3... email1, email2, email3... etc) seems the wrong way to do that.

If I don't do it that way, I would assume I need to create a separate XML file for each "account" ... all with identical fields, just named differently such as     R.xml.acct1, R.xml.acct2, etc...   Then calling the appropriate R.xml file during the addPreferencesFromResources as well as the saving calls.

The question is, is that the correct or best way to do this?   Is there something else I am missing?  Or is using an SQL database the better way to handle this?  Maybe I should just give up on preferences and use SQL and create my own input/edit screens?

Comment: I think your last option is the best. Honestly with that many entries i would not want to use shared preferences. And creating your one input and edit screens is not hard and you will have full control over exactly what happens how and when the data gets entered into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter,

You can use the db if you are familiar with sqlite and all the code needed to handle it. That is not a bad option; however, it might be overkill for what you are doing.

If you want to use SharedPreferences, I would recommend creating xml files for each account and storing the data in an xml file. This will require you to create a view to capture the data and not use a preference fragment.

Here is some code that could help you get started for saving the data.

```
public static boolean setAccountInformation(final Context context, final String accountName, final Account account) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(accountName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("account_name", account.name);
        editor.putString("account_email", account.email);
        ...
        return editor.commit();
}

public static Account getAccountInformation(final Context context, final String accountName) {
    Account account = new Account();
    SharedPreferences preference = context.getSharedPreferences(accountName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    account.email = preference.getString("account_name", null);
    account.name  = preference.getString("account_email", null);
    ...
    return account;
}
```

This will require you to keep track of the account (xml) file names. You could store them in a string array in another shared preference and add or remove the names when accounts are added or removed.

Comment: to use multiple XML files, can they be identical just different name?   Second question, instead of using your example code, wouldn't addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefacct) in the onCreate() work changing the name from prefacct to prefacct2, prefacct3, etc... whatever we called the XML file?

Comment: Peter, you would have create the xml files to pass. By using the methods above you can create the form data 1 time and then store the data as shared preference or push it wherever you want (DB, web service, etc). I am not 100% sure if you could not do what you want to do, but it might be a little difficult. You would just need to get the data out and store it differently. Share Preferences like you have is meant to be saved as settings not storage as I am suggesting.

Comment: Ok, if I am understanding your example and suggestion correctly... I create one XML file and use it with your sample code, but then store or retrieve the data from another source (DB, ARRAY, ETC).  The XML is just basically a "place holder" for the data during the preference fragment for inputing and changing the data.  Corrrect?

Comment: The code above will create an xml (shared preference) file with whatever you have for the accountName. That will allow you to name it whatever you want. In the setAccountInformation method you can add whatever fields you want that all files will share. Then all you have to do is keep track of all the different xml files you create. Use the getAccountInformation to retrieve the data from the specified file and it will create an Account object to return. The reference to the other storage types was just an example of what you could do if you didnt use shared preference xml files.